# Should I stop a thread after it's work is done?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a activity where I am creating 3-4 threads for doing different tasks in a  Activity, where I insert data into database and get some data from net and POST on a site for data and else. I wanted to ask that i have counter via which  I will know when that thread's work has been finished, so should I close(stop) that thread ? Does the same apply to asyncTask too?

Comment: If you start a thread the normal way and the code in run() is ready, run will return and your thread will finish too.

Comment: " run will return " means? Does it have a timeout for idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple Thread as example:

This is the Runnable

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

}
```

and you start a Thread to run the runnable

```
(new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
```

As soon as the `System.out.println` is finished, the Thread is stopped, and no additional operation is required to close/dispose it.

Comment: Okay, I got it, Thanks!